# Dropzone.js: .zip as acceptedFiles in Safari not working

Tags: dropzone.js

I have the following accepted files with Dropzone.js:
acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/jpg,.zip",

When clicking in Safari, the ZIP-files are disabled in the Explorer window to upload. By dropping it's working fine. The clicking is working fine on other browsers as well.

I guess it has to do with the filename extension instead of mime-types. But as there are several different mime-types for zip-files, I'd like to stick with the more general .zip file extension.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add to acceptedFiles "application/zip" - then even safari accept ZIP files.